# How do I convert the values in a Map from List of Strings to a String?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, multimap

Currently I have a map containing key as a string & values as a list of strings. Map>

How can I convert these values from list of strings to a single string? 
eg:
Below are the values which are contained in my map .

```
{id=[1057-27620], name=[apple,mango,banana], color=[apple:red, mango:yellow, banana:black&yellow], place=[greece]}
```

I want the above to be stored in `Map<String,String>`as

```
{id="1057-27620", name="apple,mango,banana", color="apple:red, mango:yellow, banana:black&yellow", place="greece"}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Iterating and building a String with `StringBuilder` - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Any code yet ? hint: walkthrough your list and concatenate strings to a single string and add to another map

Comment: The question is why do you want to concatenate strings which are different?. The next time you want to use these values as seperate strings, you will have to split them again.

Comment: two different strings? I want to convert the values which are in form of a list to one string, so that I won't have to iterate through the list while printing out the key - value pairs in freemarker. I basically want a single key & infront of that multiple values as a string. Once I have that in a map , I can then use it to iterate in freemarker

Answer (score 0):

The problems comes down to how to convert from `List<String>` to the `String` containing the element separated by comma. Well, use [Guava's `Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/2af254b44e70ff13e57fc707f814157df3c30a62/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) here.

Here's an example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aabc", "bcd", "aba");
String listToString = Joiner.on(", ").join(list); 
System.out.println(listToString);   // "aabc, bcd, aba"
```

I would leave the job of applying this to convert `Map<String, List<String>>` to `Map<String, String>` on you.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving all values inside" " and seperate it using ,

Answer (score -1):

get list of string and apply `List.toString().replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","");` and build another map